# Customizing serializeArray( ) to a different array format

Tags: javascript, jquery, serializearray

Was wondering what I'd have to do to convert my data that is currently being sent like this (using `serializeArray()`)

```
data[0][name]:title
data[0][value]:This is my sample title
data[1][name]:description
data[1][value]:This is an (optional) description but I'm filling it out as an example
data[2][name]:source
data[2][value]:http://www.cnn.com
data[3][name]:category
data[3][value]:animals
```

To send like this instead:

```
data[title]:This is my sample title
data[description:This is an (optional) description but I'm filling it out as an example
data[source]:http://www.cnn.com
data[category]:animals
```

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        var $data = $('#js-serialize').serializeArray();
        console.log($data);
        $.post('/echo/json', {
            'data': $data
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, 'json');
        return false;

    });

});

<form id="js-serialize">
<input name="title" placeholder="title" />
<input name="description" placeholder="description" />
<input name="source" placeholder="source" />
<input name="category" placeholder="category"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>​
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/someprimetime/bnPwN/5/

Comment: What is the purpose of structuring it differently? Unless you specify otherwise, jQuery will turn it into the same thing when it sends it to the server anyway. Form params.

Comment: @KevinB because of the way CakePHP works, I've found that this is the only acceptable way to "serialize" my form without having to specifically send each value individually.

Comment: Right, but won't jquery take whatever data you pass in whether it's an object, array of objects, or a simple query string, and convert it to the same form parameters to be sent?

Comment: With your current code, you should see `$_POST["description"]` and it should also be available in the cakePHP format, unless it's doing something different behind the scenes.

Comment: @KevinB Kind of... when I set `$this->request->data` to my model, it has to in a particular format such as `$this->request->data['title']` or something similar (without the name/value index). I mean I could do it like that, but it's just easier for me to do it like this in the controller.

Comment: What I was getting at is that regardless of whether you pass in a querystring, an array of objects, or an object, you end up with the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/bnPwN/6/ (check console) I'm not sure why that would make any difference in CakePHP, but if it works it works i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for an object representation instead of an array.

jQuery does not support something like `serializeObject()` out of the box. [This plugin](http://danheberden.com/jquery-plugin-serializeobject-2011-04-01/), however, seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but:

```
function serializeObject(serializedArray){
    var serializedObj={};
    serializedArray.forEach(function(i){
       serializedObj[i.name]=i.value;       
    });
    return serializedObj;
}
```